Handle current route in static nuxt3
I have a nuxt app that uses ssr:false.
and i generate the files by nuxi generate
the issue is that some styles wont work beause they are dependant on this function :
const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';

const activepath = (path) => {
  if (isClient) {
    const localizedPath = localePath(path);
    return route.path === localizedPath;
  }
  return false;
};

The app is deployed in nginx . It works in local server but on static its not working .
i read some where that you cant access the route.path in static mode .
in this case how can i handle this issue?
the page styles wont work on refresh but only works when u navigate inside the app
